# macOS High Sierra Security Update 2020-002 stuck at "calculating time remaining"

Tags: macos, high-sierra, startup

On a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010), macOS 10.13.6, when attempting to install Security Update 2020-002, it gets stuck at the boot screen (white background, grey Apple) "calculating time remaining." Leaving the Mac for hours results in no change.

Two ways to get back to a working Mac:

- Boot into recovery mode and reinstall macOS High Sierra
- Boot into recovery mode, open Terminal, and move aside `/Library/Updates`

From `install.log`:

```
May 18 20:45:50 MacBook-Pro OSInstaller[549]: PackageKit: Extracting file:///Volumes/Untitled/Library/Updates/AtomicUpdates/061-90748/SecUpd2020-002HighSierra.pkg (destination=/Volumes/Untitled/.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware/FDD0851E-0C89-4857-A385-B697B0816850.activeSandbox/Root, uid=0)
May 18 20:45:51 MacBook-Pro OSInstaller[549]: Initial SU Progress: True progress received. Ending timer.
May 18 20:45:51 MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[180]: Status is "Installing: About 34 minutes remaining"
May 18 20:46:21 MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[180]: Status is "Installing: About 33 minutes remaining"
May 18 20:47:31 MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[180]: Status is "Installation is in progress. Calculating time remaining…"
May 18 20:48:36 MacBook-Pro OSInstaller[549]: Can not connect to /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.socket: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried using the DMG available at support.apple.com/downloads? This might help. Also, try updating in Safe Mode to eliminate third party apps from causing this issue.

Comment: "Safe mode" shouldn't be relevant here, because this all happens _at boot_, before anything loads (kexts, login items, fonts, etc.). No reason to believe manually installing the pkg from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2034?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US will have a different result than letting SU install it.

Comment: Security Update 2020-003 has just been released: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2042

Comment: 2020-003 installed without incident on this machine.